# How to use translation in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, redirect, python-babel, flask-babel

I have an application in which I have managed to use translations for romanian and english. I want to press the button "english" and get the website translated in english and when pressing "romanian" the website should translate to romanian.

I have managed to do this so far, but whenever I click on whether english or romanian, the website goes to the home page. How can I redirect the flask page to the current page, for example contact page? Now, if I am on the contact page and press "english", the website gets translated in english but redirects me to home page. I am using Flask Babel for translation.

For the button I have the following code in `index.html`:

```html
<a class="dropdown-item" href="/language/en">English</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="/language/ro">Romanian</a>
```

And the code from `app.py` for the translations is:

```py
LANGUAGES = {
    'en': 'English',
    'ro': 'Romanian'
}
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/language/<language>')
def set_language(language=None):
    session['language'] = language
    return redirect(url_for('home'))

@babel.localeselector
def get_locale():
    try:
        language = session['language']
    except KeyError:
        language = None
    if language is not None:
        return language
    return request.accept_languages.best_match(LANGUAGES.keys())

@app.context_processor
def inject_conf_var():
    return dict(
        AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES=LANGUAGES,
        CURRENT_LANGUAGE=session.get('language', request.accept_languages.best_match(LANGUAGES.keys())))
```

Comment: Well, the website goes to home cause on the function set_language you redirect to home, maybe try to play with the code there? (:

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14277067/redirect-back-in-flask

Comment: @YoelNisanov, I put home there because I cannot find a way to just change the language and stay on the current page...

Comment: maybe something like '/language/{0}'.format(language) in the redirect instead of home? or is it just a rest request and if it is then you gotta get the current url from the session and redirect to this url?

Comment: I have added the solution in the original post. @Elephant90 thank you for the link, there i found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def redirect_url(default='index'):
    return request.args.get('next') or \
           request.referrer or \
           url_for(default)


@app.route('/language/<language>')
def set_language(language=None):
    session['language'] = language
    return redirect(redirect_url())  # redirect to current url
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/61124433/2) to the question [How to use translation in Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61124433/how-to-use-translation-in-flask) by the OP [moro_922](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13183329/moro-922) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>