# Flask go back to the previous previous url (go back twice)

Tags: python, flask, redirect, referrer

I am using flask for a recipe app. When a user edits a recipe, I'd like to go back to where they came from when they click "update" and submit the form. Since the referrer of the request is the "editrecipe" url, I need to find a way to send them back twice. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14277067/redirect-back-in-flask) helps me to go back once, but ideally I'd like to do something like this:

```
redirect_url = request.args.get('previous')[-2]
```

OR

```
redirect_url = request.referrer(-2)
```

Neither of these work (for obvious reasons), I was just wondering if there's a way to access the browser history and go back twice?

Comment: How are you authenticating a user. Do you use `flask-session`?

Comment: I do use `flask-session`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you can try something like [this](https://gist.github.com/reinefjord/0e940bd3b07404199942c1fec038898f).

The basic idea here to have a after request handler and push the visited URIs to your session's history. Now, when you want to redirect, then get the history variable from `flask-session` and simply redirect to the last_before value.